# Find the killer's name!

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, lateral-thinking

A notorious serial killer going by the pseudonym "N" has dispatched a letter to the FBI after committing 45 homicides. He is characterized to be extremely intelligent and sends mysterious cryptographic letters to the police once a month, for the mere reason being "messing around".

This time, the letter received was;

```
Dear informants, 
I know you want me, and you know I want you too.
But are you a genius?
You gotta have some genius to catch me.
And you know what? I am sad...You have about a thousand suspects of me.
And none of them is me! 
I am depressed to see such failure, specially by the glorious FBI.
So, below....is some crypted content. In the content, contains my full name.
If you solve it, you win! And I? Well...I lose. Unfortunately...
You'll try.

BQzkmcmaIJSaiNysehtMtlzqUScmtz

Sincerely,
N
```

What is his name?

**Hint:**

> The encrypted text contains the name in the format, "MyNameIs[XYZ]". The first letters of the last and first name may or may not be capitalized.

Comment: So tempting to post a troll answer saying "no, I'm not" :-p Cool username btw!

Comment: In these situations, it's always Rumplestiltskin, no?

Comment: What if his name is actually BQzkmcmaIJSaiNysehtMtlzqUScmtz and he became a serial killer because other people used to tease him?

Comment: Does `BQzkmcmaIJSaiNysehtMtlzqUScmtz` include punctuations and spaces? That may explain why 21 unique characters are involved.

Comment: I added a little hint, since the puzzle is perhaps quite difficult to solve.

Comment: Does XYZ mean that the full name is composed of 3 names?

Comment: Ofcourse not! The name is composed of many two names; the first and last name. There is no middle name involved. XYZ was merely an example to feed your curiosity.

Comment: Finally, are we looking for a occidental name (like John Smith) or esotic name (like Abdul Shakoor)? 
I mean, are we able to recognize it as a name once we find it?

Comment: Username "God" and exactly 42 rep - this is surely significant.

Comment: Mr. Leoll2, I admire your expertise in solving ridiculously hard puzzles, and also that you belong from my native country of Italy, but if I told you everything...this puzzle's difficulty would be minimized down to a factor of 1.

Comment: -1 for the title. Change the title and I might reverse it :)

Comment: Am I the only who noticed that the letters of MyNameIs are all contained inside the string, also respecting upper and lowercase?  So, that may be an anagram, though the scarcity of remaining vowels makes the task even harder.

Comment: @leoll2 Plus, by removing the letters MyNameIs, the remaining 22 letters contains 3 z's, 2 q's and only 1 u.

Comment: Is the poor grammar in the message intentional?

Comment: Ian, N is not your average Ted Bundy. He never received a proper education, so that might explain the poor grammar present in his message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with:

`BQzkmcmaIJSaiNysehtMtlzqUScmtz`

Remove `MyNameIs`:

`BQzk cm  JSai    ht tlzqUScmtz`

Group the remaining letters:

- First letters: `BJQSSU`
- Vowels: `ai`
- Others: `cchklmmqttzzz`

Make a name with them:

> Jack Smith

Remove its letters:

`BQz                 tlzqUScmtz`

Nice.

Comment: Holy crab, I accidentally wrote John Smith in one of the comments, if this is correct, I was unintentionally damn close! 
By the way, it would be sad if the left letters were there just to be discarded without criterion...

Comment: You solved it purely like a chess grandmaster, Miguel! Congratulations. I added an answer which will further elucidate the solution.

Comment: Too smart! Impressive explanation to the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Miguel solved the puzzle but not completely, I'll further elucidate.

The value is;

```
BQzkmcmaIJSaiNysehtMtlzqUScmtz
```

And as the hint states, the killer's name will start off with "MyNameIs" and where is this? The letters of "MyNameIs"  and the killer's name are located exquisitely here;

BQz**kmcmaIJSaiNysehtM**tlzqUScmtz

So, we'll take em' out to grab the answer:

```
kmcmaIJSaiNysehtM
```

Then, after taking out the letters of "MyNameIs", we're left with:

```
kmcaJSiht
```

Eureka! After assorting it in a proper order, The killer's name is;

```
JackSmith
```

And the complete hidden text was:

```
MyNameIsJackSmith
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that 9 characters of the name should be upper case.  It is also unlikely that the name length is 30 characters. Therefore the killer's name is:

> one of these 16 names that use about half of the characters from the encryted string:
>
>  Mateusz Michalski
>  Michal Stantejsky
>  Matthias Kuntzel
>  Michael Stickman
>  Sebastian Schulz
>  Shamus McClaskey
>  Timea Bacsinszky
>  Chaim Maltinsky
>  Helmut Bakaitis
>  Hikmet Sulayman
>  Jacques Bialski
>  Jacques Cassini
>  Jacques Haitkin
>  James McQuilkin
>  Klaus Steinbach
>  Maciej Szmatiuk

Comment: A marvelous attempt, but wrong. None of the names listed match, or even slightly close to the killer's name.